# Will running exe in memory perform better than dll in .NET?

Tags: .net, performance, dynamic, dll, exe

I need to dynamically load a dll/exe into memory based on database configurations. I can either

```
1) load the dll or 
2) load an win form exe which calls the dll.
```

Is there a performance difference between these two approaches?

Comment: well if you have to load also the exe to run the dll this will take loading time and memory. But without the exe to run the dll, what will be loading the dll and executing its functions? Is this code faster and lighter than the exe?

Comment: I would bet that directly loading a DLL runs faster.  But note that having an EXE will launch a separate process space.  The DLL will run in the same process space as the calling program.

Comment: @Davide Piras, I will have a windows service that will load and run a dll or exe (I haven't decided which to use) in a separate app domain for each datatable record. It periodically checks the table and make sure the current app domains are active. It will create new app domain and load new dll/exe if a new db record is entered. The table contains paths to dll/exe. Hopefully this is more clear now.